# iterate through a javascript map with foreach and getting the key value with arrow function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach, arrow-functions

For some reason, I am not getting any thing returned.  I am getting the console log printed with the correct values.  Does anyone know why?  Thx!

```
renderRow() {
  const { Row, Cell } = Table;
  return this.props.registeredAccountsToCostMap.forEach((map, i) => {
      console.log(map[0], ' ', map[1], ' ', i);
      return (
        <Row key={map[0]}>
          <Cell>{map[0]}</Cell>
          <Cell>{map[1]}</Cell>
        </Row>
      )
  })
```

Comment: When you say map, do you mean the data structure `new Map`?

Comment: You want to transform each element in the array and return the transformed array; so, don't use `forEach`, use `map`. `return this.props.registeredAccountsToCostMap.map(`

Comment: As the documents clearly state, and has been described in many, many questions here on SO, `forEach` does not return anything, and the return value from the callback you pass it is ignored. Perhaps you want `Array#map`? Speaking of which, "map" do you mean array?

Comment: registeredaccountstocostmap is using data structure map.  map is not a function of the map data structure.  i tried that and originally and got a syntax error.  then i looked at the documentation and found the closest thing to arrary.map for the map data structure is using foreach.  I am getting the correct values from the console.log call.  It's returning an array into the map variable.